# Why no bookmark is added automatically for my canvas-app?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, bookmarks

Why no bookmark is added automatically for my canvas-app to user's app list, after the user engages with it? The same app had functioned totally fine a few weeks ago.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a programming question - if you think this is a facebook bug you should file a bug in the bug tracker

Answer (score 2):

> Starting today, application bookmarks can move "above the fold" (above the "More" link), based on how recently the user used the application. We're now displaying six bookmarks above the fold, which gives users an extra slot for one-click access to your applications.
>
> If a user hasn't clicked a bookmark within the past 30 days, it will move below the fold. If multiple applications have been used recently and are above the fold, their order will be determined by the order in which each bookmark was added. Also, we will automatically bookmark applications for users when they visit an application that has not been bookmarked.

Source : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/396

There was before (with FBML) a way to create a bookmark button ([See Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/bookmark/)) but that option was removed and FBML is now deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem, i solved it by adding 'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/your_app_name/' to $facebook->getLoginUrl array paremeters.
This then redirect back to your app url, making that app the latest used.

```
                    $dialogbox= "". $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                            'req_perms' => 'publish_stream',
                            'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/your_app/'

                    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The bookmarks are defined by usage or user preference - we as developers have no control over what icons appear as bookmarks.

Comment: If anyone has any evidence against this answer - please... DONT keep it to yourself! ;)

Comment: All my apps were appreaed under user's Apps list immediately after he has granted permmsision to app und used it. since a few weeks it is not so. Is there any new regulation on facebook which prevent it?